# Converting hex strings to decimal format: Why am I getting different results in JavaScript and Python?

Tags: javascript, python, hex, decimal, parseint

Getting different values converting the same hex string to decimal format in Javascript and Python!

Assume we have this hex string:

`1f42c803ac5f267802916924e52a3e1b`

We want to convert this string to decimal format.
what can we do in JavaScript:

`parseInt('1f42c803ac5f267802916924e52a3e1b', 16)`

what can we do in Python:

`int('1f42c803ac5f267802916924e52a3e1b', 16)`

why these 2 function return different values?

Comment: I don't see how they are different, apart from that you need to use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) for the JS counterpart (e.g. `BigInt('0x1f42c803ac5f267802916924e52a3e1b')`) to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get different values when converting the exact hex string to decimal format in JavaScript and Python due to a difference in how the two languages handle large numbers. Python has no real limitation on how large a number can get. In JavaScript, you have the limitation of 32 bits (4 bytes) to store an integer.

The `parseInt` function converts the hexadecimal string to a 32-bit signed integer in JavaScript. The maximum value that a 32-bit signed integer can represent is 2,147,483,647. The resulting value exceeds this maximum, so JavaScript truncates the bits beyond the 32nd bit, leading to a loss of precision. (Note how long your hexadecimal number is – the decimal version will be even longer, using more bits).

The `int` function does not have the same limitation in Python. It can handle arbitrarily large integers without losing precision. So, when you convert the hex string to a decimal using int in Python, you get the correct and precise result.

---

You can use the [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) data type introduced in ECMAScript 2020 (ES2020) to obtain the correct result. `BigInt` allows you to work with arbitrarily large integers.

```js
const decimalValue = BigInt('0x1f42c803ac5f267802916924e52a3e1b');
```

The resulting `decimalValue` will be a `BigInt` object, not a normal JavaScript `number` type.

Comment: In JS `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` is the largest accurate integer (52 bits for the mantissa). `parseInt`'s 32-bit conversion is a separate issue.